# How to run Docker container from local Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-desktop

I built a Docker image with a simple .Net Core console app that just display messages in a loop. After build, I can see that it is registered with my local Docker Desktop (see screenshot below). But when I run it, it seems running, but I don't see any console display the messages. What am I missing here?
When I click on the console icon on the right, it just displays an empty console as this
[image]

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TPA-Solution-0.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "TPA-Solution-0.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "TPA-Solution-0.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TPA-Solution-0.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TPA-Solution-0.dll"]
enter code here
```

Here is my docker-compose.ymal:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  tpa-solution-0:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tpasolution0
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

The log doesn't have much in it. So is the console attached to it... I wonder if my program is actually running while the container is running.
[image]

Comment: either you can click on the console icons on right or copy the id mentioned below and attach https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/

Comment: You would need to add parts of the Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml for anybody to begin to understand and assist.  In general the logs  that aare displayed for a container will be the output of CMD. you can view the logs through docker desktop by clicking on the container. You can view the logs from cli with `docker logs --follow <container name>` in your case container_name is `epic_rhodes`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

double click on container name to see your console logs,
you can also attach to container , if needed using console icon

Part 2:
[image]
1.Console App:

```
    while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Console.WriteLine("test");
}
```

2. DockerFile

> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
> WORKDIR /app
>
> ```
> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
> WORKDIR /src
> COPY ["ConsoleApp2/ConsoleApp2.csproj", "ConsoleApp2/"]
> RUN dotnet restore "ConsoleApp2/ConsoleApp2.csproj"
> COPY . .
> WORKDIR "/src/ConsoleApp2"
> RUN dotnet build "ConsoleApp2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
>
> FROM build AS publish
> RUN dotnet publish "ConsoleApp2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
>
> FROM base AS final
> WORKDIR /app
> COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
> ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp2.dll"]
> ```

3 Compose File

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  consoleapp2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}consoleapp2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ConsoleApp2/Dockerfile
```

Comment: Please see my updates above. The log doesn't have much in it. And the console is empty, too.

Comment: @Alexu Could you try replicating with above

Comment: As it turned out, my issue was caused by a hidden build error. It didn't show until I did the Build DockerFile. I am able to run the container successfully when I fixed the build error. Thank you kunal for your input!